# Set Leaflet marker to always stay in the middle of the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, svelte, openstreetmap

I'm working on a SvelteKit project where we're moving from Google Maps to Open Street Maps using Leaflet.js. With Google Maps we have a marker that always stays in the center of the map even when panning around.

I want to do the same thing with Leaflet. But the marker always stays on the default location on the map.

I currently have the marker defined as such

```js
currentPositionMarker = new L.marker(map.getCenter(), {
  icon: icon // icon is defined earlier in the code
}).addTo(map)

...

function centerMarkerOnMap(map) {
  currentPositionMarker.setLatLng(map.getCenter())
}

...

map.on('moveend', centerMarkerOnMap)
```

Currently I get `Uncaught TypeError: map.getCenter is not a function` in the console. I'm not sure why, since I'm using `map.getCenter()` to set the original marker position with no issues.

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because the parameter passed to the function is a `LeafletEvent`.

The map object is available in `event.target`:

```
function centerMarkerOnMap(event) {
  currentPositionMarker.setLatLng(event.target.getCenter())
}

map.on('moveend', centerMarkerOnMap)
```

I've prepared a demo where the marker always stays in the center of the map:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/marker-always-ceter?file=index.js